# C++ Does Not Catch Exception

Tags: c++, mysql, exception, try-catch

When I run the following code:

```
    try{
        m_driver = get_driver_instance();
        m_conn = m_driver->connect("tcp://ipaddress:3306","username","password");
        m_conn->setSchema("mydatabase");
    }catch (sql::SQLException e) {
        std::cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        std::cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << std::endl;
        std::cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        std::cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        std::cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << std::endl;
    }
```

I get the output:

```
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'sql::SQLException'
    Abort trap: 6
```

Instead of my exception. What is up?

**Note:** I am using the g++ 4.8.2 compiler with c++11 enabled.

Comment: Try `catch (const sql::SQLException& e)` and add another catch block for `std::exception` afterwards.

Comment: Uhm... start in gdb, and do `catch throw`. That will tell you where the exception is thrown (might be somewhere else).

Comment: Smells like some incompatibilities between the runtime of the mysql lib and your runtime.